# How to validate source and target tables are sync or not in AWS DMS task ongoing replication?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-dms

I would like to know how to validate source and target database tables are in sync at some point of time with AWS DMS task type as "Full load, ongoing replication"?

Source database Tables are:

1. catalog_table
2. Job_table (job_id, count)

One ETL job (outside of DMS task) inserts data into "catalog_table" with 1000 records (example) every time, then at the end it inserts record into "job_table" with job_id and count as "number of records" inserted into catalog_table.

And my DMS task running and continuously copying data into target DB (which is working fine).

Here, I want to validate source and target databases "catalog_table" data for each job_id which inserted into job_table. What kind of events or mechanism I can use in this scenario? Appreciate your time.

Note: Source and Target are RDS instances.